# Airborne Smell Modelling

Tags: software-recommendations, modelling, references

I am wondering if anyone can point me to a resource that will provide a way to model out smells of a garbage dump based on wind? I have been searching through articles on down wind pollution models and the like but have not been able to successfully find anything.

I am fine with using any open source solutions or ESRI based products.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer. What was wrong with the downwind pollution models in the articles you did find? How specialised do you want it? Household garbage? Recycling facilities? Land fill sites?

Comment: @spacedman thanks for the comment. In terms of specifics, I am looking to model out smell downwind from a landfill site.  I was not able to find any tools or readings on the subject so I defaulted here.

Comment: Have you looked into citizen complaint databases?  It seems like [odor complaints](http://www.tceq.state.tx.us/complaints/odor_complaint.html) could be used.

Comment: Have you looked at ALOHA? Never used it myself. http://response.restoration.noaa.gov/aloha

Comment: @recurvata this is perfect! if you put it in an answer I can close off the question.

Comment: If you find wind direction data, please let me know.

Comment: @Tom I have found wind data from the [National Digital Forecast Database](http://ndfd.weather.gov/technical.htm) via [wind map](http://hint.fm/wind/). There is also a source from ESRI for [Simple Wind Speed and Direction](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=9d73d734b276419ab2015eb05c3d976b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [ALOHA](http://response.restoration.noaa.gov/aloha) from NOAA. They have data and feeds for a variety of meteorological factors. ALOHA calculates wind plumes.